# How is the sixth watch connected by blood?

Tags: night-watch-cycle, sergei-lukyanenko, sixth-watch

In the 6th book of the *Night Watch* cycle, the story its much about the "sixth watch", a mysterious group of people. They consist of representants of six different parties, namely: Vampires, Light, Darkness, witches, a prophet and a mirror.

> At the end of the book, Anton Gorodezki announces the members of the sixth watch, shortly before the twilight-god enters the room. They consist of Arina (witch), Nadya Gorodezki (light), Kescha (prophet), Egor (mirror), Zabulon (dark), and surprisingly Kostya (vampire).

The last part seems a little "rushed", since everything happens pretty quickly without much explanation. One requirement for the members of the sixth watch is also, that they are connected by blood. This is the tricky part I don't quite understood.

> The members are seemingly connected via Anton.
>  Nadya: Anton's daughter
>  Zabulon: Anton's grandfather
>  Egor: Got some of Anton's blood in the first book
>  Kescha: Connected to Nadya by a blood oath, and thus connected via Anton
>  Kostya: ??? I was still surprised that he's alive
>  Arina: She says multiple times that she has no connection to Zabulon or Anton or anyone else

So, how are they all connected, especially the last two?

Comment: sorry i can't help you with your question but thank you for asking, i had read the 4th book years ago and thought that was the end of it.  So glad to see that he's written two more.  now it's off to amazon.

Comment: The author once said, that he wanted to continue the story when Antons daughter was a little older. In book 6 she is 14/15. However, he also said hes very bad at writing "in the future", so he simple waited

Comment: Kostya appears in book 3 alot, but does not drink Anton's blood. At the end of book 3 Kostya 'disappears' until the end of book 6. So sadly, no.

The only vampire i know that took blood from Anton died shortly after.

Comment: Since I've just read the book, I remember that Arina gave her blood to Kostya's father to re-write the Fuaran, so she is connected to Anton through Kostya. But I can't remember how he was connected in the first place...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the book in my hand I can finally answer:

- Nadya is the Light One, she is Anton's daughter.
- Zabulon is the Dark One, also he is Anton's grandfather.
- "One who sees" (a Prophet) is Innokenti (Kesha) - he made a blood pact with Nadya.
- "One who has no power" (a Mirror) is Egor - he has been Called by vampiress, Anton used blood to attune himself to the same Call and save him.
- "One who takes the Power" (a Vampire) is a mix-up of vampires with Kostya on top (Kostya jokes that its he is the top "[Russian Doll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X6KW.jpg)"). What is important, one of them is the vampiress that was Calling Egor, other one is Kostya's father.
- "One who senses" (a witch) is Arina - she gave Kostya's father her blood to increase his power.

Comment: Thank you! The explanation for Kostya and Arina are great. I thought they were more directly connected to Anton, but it seems i was mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Well, spoilers ahead, obviously.

The members of the sixth watch don't have to be directly connected by blood. Arina even stated that the former sixth watch wasn't conneceted that way either. They are connected by the shed blood of the sacrifice they choose. They are all connected by Anton Gorodezki through love and hatred, gallantry and betrayal, power and weakness. That's why Kostya had to be resurreted since no other vampire shares that bond with Anton. At least thats my conclusion after reading the last book.